# replace Yes, No to 1, 0 in multiple columns in r

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I need to replace the Yes and No values to 1 and 0 in 200 columns.

I was using with the command

```
data %>% mutate(x=ifelse(x=="Yes", 1,0))
```

but i have to go through each column at a time, and i was wondering if there was any way i could do it all at once.

Comment: `data[] <- lapply(data, function(x) as.integer(x == "Yes"))`

Answer (score 3):

You may use `ifelse` on the entire data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(v1=c("Yes","No"), v2=c("No","Yes"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ifelse(df == "Yes", 1, 0)

     v1 v2
[1,]  1  0
[2,]  0  1
```

This coerces to a matrix, but given that your output would be completely numeric, maybe this doesn't matter to you.

Comment: I  think that makes Yes become 1, but it is non selective about what becomes 0. Iy you had yes, no, maybe and undecided, then yes would be 1 and anything else, including columns with useful but not logical values would become 0. At the very least newbies should be counseled to not assign the results back to the same name. (I do see tht you did not assign to anything.)

Comment: I think I have answered the question asked, and you are bringing up edge cases which we do not even know to exist.

Answer (score 3):

This is the `dplyr` version (since your using it anyway).

Just put your calculation in a function...

```
helperFunction <- function(x){
    ifelse(x=="Yes", 1,0)
}
```

...and then you can apply this function to every column.

```
data %>%
    mutate_all(helperFunction)
```

Answer (score 3):

Following [Tim Biegeleisen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59786032/8245406), stating that a function can be used on the entire dataframe, this code works:

```
data <- data.frame(v1=c("Yes","No"), v2=c("No","Yes"))

data[] <- as.integer(data == "Yes")

data
#  v1 v2
#1  1  0
#2  0  1
```

And it's probably faster than `ifelse`, which can be useful with a 200 column dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code

```
df[] <- +(df == "Yes")
```

and you will get

```
> df
  col1 col2
1    1    0
2    0    1
3    1    1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(col1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L), col2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```